# What's the most efficient way to get the minimum and maximum value of two properties of a set of objects

Tags: swift, algorithm, comparison, max

I'm writing an app where performance is most important and I have to iterate through a set of workstations which all have positions with x- and y-coordinates. This is the relevant part of the workstation and the position:

```
struct Workstation {
    let position: Position
}

struct Position {
    let x, y: Int

    func distance(to otherPosition: Position) -> Int {
        return abs(self.x - otherPosition.x) + abs(self.y - otherPosition.y)
    }
}
```

The goal in this specific case is to get half the length of the diagonal of the rectangle surrounding all workstations, but I have to do some other calculations later on as well (like getting the center coordinate of all workstations).

I came up with two possible solutions (note: `layout.workstations` is of type `Set<Workstation>`):

**Solution 1**

```
private func getSurroundingRectangeScore(for layout: FactoryLayout) -> Double {
    var minX = Int.max
    var maxX = Int.min
    var minY = Int.max
    var maxY = Int.min
    for workstation in layout.workstations {
        let pos = workstation.position
        if pos.x < minX { minX = pos.x }
        if pos.x > maxX { maxX = pos.x }
        if pos.y < minY { minY = pos.y }
        if pos.y > maxY { maxY = pos.y }
    }
    let minPosition = Position(x: minX, y: minY)
    let maxPosition = Position(x: maxX, y: maxY)
    return Double(minPosition.distance(to: maxPosition)) / 2
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
private func getSurroundingRectangeScore(for layout: FactoryLayout) -> Double {
    let xValues = layout.workstations.map { $0.position.x }
    let yValues = layout.workstations.map { $0.position.y }

    guard let minX = xValues.min(), let maxX = xValues.max(), let minY = yValues.min(), let maxY = yValues.max() else {
        fatalError("Minima or Maxima could not be determined!")
    }

    let minPosition = Position(x: minX, y: minY)
    let maxPosition = Position(x: maxX, y: maxY)
    return Double(minPosition.distance(to: maxPosition)) / 2
}
```

My understanding is that solution 1 iterates through the workstations only once and fills all needed coordinate variables in one swoop. Solution 2 is better readable, but has to iterate the workstation set two times and the resulting arrays four times, so I guess this is by far worse. So my question would be, if my assumption is right and if there's an even more efficient way to calculate here?

Comment: I would think O(n) would be the best complexity possible for this problem, so your first solution is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: Are the x and y coordinates independent of eachother? if they are then you'll be able to achieve O(log n) which is significantly faster. If not then I'm afraid O(n) will most likely be your best bet (this is of course without seeing the rest of the requirements of the app/algo)

Comment: @TPN1994 if I understand your question correctly: they are independent for this calculation, yes, because I only need the minimum of all x values and all y values to form two new positions (in contrast to finding the minimum and maximum position (x,y) of all given positions - which is not needed here). How would I achieve O(log n) then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't guess about which one is worse. Run it, and measure it. (There's also an option besides your two, which is using the built-in sort routine and then looking at the ends of the result.)

Second, if it's a requirement that accessing this information always be as fast as possible, then use a data structure that supports the requirement. Find the values for the initial collection once, then update them each time an element is added. Instead of throwing away information and repeatedly doing the same *N* comparisons, do just four each time a new `Workstation` is added. Then you have a constant-time read of the extremities whenever you need them.

Comment: I‘m relatively new to coding in general and efficiency is a requirement for the first time with this project, so your answer helped me a lot. Solving this at an earlier stage and not at the point where a measurement is needed to proceed hadn‘t crossed my mind. I will implement it this way now :)

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Also maybe look at [the "heap"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).